# How can I use .dll or .lib Berkeley DB C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2015, berkeley-db

I cant connect the Berkeley DB C++ library to my VS 2015 project

1. i download a project of Berkeley DB C++: [link](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/related/berkeleydb-downloads.html)
2. i run the Berkeley_DB_vs2015.sln project from the build_windows folder and compile it
3. i get the folder x64 > Release and in it libdb_stl181.dll , libdb181.dll ,  libdb_stl181.lib, libdb181.lib, etc
   [image]

how can i use this library in other project?
im tried:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "libdb181.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "libdb_stl181.lib")
```

but i cant use:

```
#include <db_cxx.h>
```

and i cant use the library elements at all

im tried: "Add reference" in VS15 for add a .dll, but i get:
"as it is not of a type or version current project can use")

also i tried to use "Additional Library Directories" but this didnt give any result

also, the installation via NuGet probably does not suit me, since I could not do:

```
#include <dbstl_map.h>
```

ideally, i want to use this

i was able to use this (after installation via NuGet):

```
#include <db_cxx.h>
```

but this way i cant insert, for example, STL objects

based on this, i probably dont need to use NuGet.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tell us the problem you have with each method you have tried.

Comment: Please note that e.g. `#pragma comment(lib, "libdb181.lib")` tells the *linker* to *link* with the library. It doesn't modify the search path for header files. You need to modify the project settings to set up the correct paths for both preprocessor header files and linker libraries.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i use "Additional Library Directories" in "Linker". and "Additional Include Libraries". It really helped me and now i can use the library elements. But i would like to get an answer on how to properly connect this library to third-party projects, because right now it does not give me the dbstl_map.h header file and others. Also i think that now with this solution i will get some errors. Maybe there are people who have worked with Berkeley DB C++. Thanks

Comment: Please provide the error message. For  the error `cannot open source file`, use `search` in  db folder to find the file.

Comment: thank you all, I have solved this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dbstl_map.h is in directory `db-18.1.40\lang\cxx\stl`.